# Как установить картинку на фон взятую из imageview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

есть программа в которой есть картинки на выбор размещенные строчкой, то есть вы видите ряд состоящий из миниатюр, так вот для того что бы разместить картинку в imageview я должен нажать на картинку в строке и эта картинка помещается в imageview, но теперь я хочу установить выбранную картинку на фон рабочего стола телефона, как установить фон я уже понял, но мне нужно как-то передавать какой-то идентификатор выбранной картинки, и так же этот идентификатор должен использоваться для создания списка избранных, то есть при нажатии например на кнопку мы должны передавать этот идентификатор в определенное место, вроде все просто но я не знаю как вытащить идентификатор из imageview. Возможно я не сильно понятно объяснил свой вопрос если что не понятно спрашивайте буду уточнять в коментах. Вот код который использую для работы с картинками:

```
 simpleGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // set the selected image in the ImageView
                selectedImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
                int iif = selectedImageView.getId();
            }
        });
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int iif = selectedImageView.getId();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.??????? здесь нужно какой-то идентификатор????);
                WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Ниже вы можете увидеть как выглядит программа:
[image]

Comment: Если я правильно понял задачу, то вам нужно смешать два ответа [один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827644/show-intent-for-set-as-wallpaper-or-set-as-contact-picture) и [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526585/get-the-id-of-a-drawable-in-imageview)

Comment: да вы правильно поняли, но я все-равно не понял как извлечь идентификатор елемента находящегося в imageview, просто у меня этот елемент ограничен функцией работы с самим imageview и я не нашел как перекинуть этот идентификатор из одной функции в другую

Answer (score 1):

Очень путано написано. И до конца не понятно в чеп проблема.
Но мне кажется вас спасет setTag() у View (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)). Так вот вписывайте в tag идинтификатор. А по клику получайте этот getTag().